# Greenplum creates a partition table is very slow

Tags: create-table, greenplum

I run psql to create a partition table. 2 hours are gone, but it doesn't complete.  What's the problem? How to speed up? Thanks very much.

My command is

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS people_hotel CASCADE; CREATE SCHEMA people_hotel; SET SEARCH_PATH TO people_hotel, public, pg_catalog, pg_toolkit; ALTER ROLE user SET search_path TO people_hotel, public, pg_catalog, pg_toolkit;

drop table if exists people_hotel.event;
create table people_hotel.event (  event_id bigint,  time bigint, object bigint, loc_id integer )
distributed by (event_id)
PARTITION BY RANGE(time)
SUBPARTITION by range(object)
SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE (

    START (0) INCLUSIVE END (100000000) EXCLUSIVE EVERY (10000),
    DEFAULT SUBPARTITION other_object   ) (START (bigint '1527811200000') INCLUSIVE    END (bigint '1544975684280') INCLUSIVE   EVERY (bigint '2592000000'),   DEFAULT PARTITION other_time );
```

- greenplum runs with 1 master and 2 segment hosts, each host have 10 instances( 10 primary directory)
- Greenplum version: 5.9.0
- OS version: ubuntu 16.04

Comment: START (0) INCLUSIVE END (100000000) EXCLUSIVE EVERY (10000)  Are you trying to create 10,000 sub partitions for each partition?

Comment: Yes, I am. That's right.

Answer (score 0):

Do not go beyond 3K partitions. I recommend no more 1K.

Also do two level partitioning. Partition - subpartition.